# Check write permission to SQS without writing to SQS

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

If I try to write an event to SQS using the `publish` or `publishBatch` API, and my service is not granted write permission, then the API call will throw an `SqsException` with a `403` status code.

Is there any way I can check if my service has write permission to SQS without explicitly writing to that SQS?

If I call `publish` or `publishBatch` to check if I can write, then I have to send a dummy message. Is there a way I can perform this check cleanly without writing a dummy message?

I am using the Java SDK.

Comment: There seems to be no dry-run capability for message sending and trying to figure out your own permssions by looking at policy documents probably fails already at getting to all of them or once you encounter conditionals and all the complex interactions of policies. So.. sending dummy messages actually sounds like a nice alternative. Or you always grant your code permission to do something else on that queue, like getQueueAttributes and assume that one implies the other

Comment: GetQueueAttributes permission doesn't imply SendMessage permission because those are two distinct permissions in the SQS policy configuration. Looks like sending a dummy message is unavoidable.